# FullCalendar Scheduler - nowIndicator only works with initialView as Day

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Like the title says, I'm using the the FullCalendar Scheduler but I can't seem to make the `nowIndicator` to work with the `initialView` as `resourceTimelineMonth` or `resourceTimelineWeek`. The indicator stays at the `00:00` of the day.

It only works fine if the initialView is set to `resourceTimelineDay`.

My code:

```
<FullCalendar 
  v-if="employeeList && absenceList" 
  :options="calendarOptions"
/>

(...)

data() {
    return {
      employeeList: null,
      absenceList: null,
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [ resourceTimelinePlugin ],
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'today prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek,resourceTimelineMonth'
        },
        locales: allLocales,
        locale: this.$i18n.locale,
        initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
        resourceGroupField: 'department',
        resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Colaboradores ',
        resourceOrder: 'department,title',
        nowIndicator: true,
        businessHours: [ 
          { 
            daysOfWeek: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], 
            startTime: null, 
            endTime: null, 
          } 
        ],
        height: 600,
        resources: this.getEmployeesArray,
        events: this.getApprovedAbsencesArray,
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I assume you're using fullCalendar 5? If not, please state the exact version. I can't reproduce this with v5. Works fine on a standard demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PomNNoe . P.S. There is no such option as "locales". Only "locale" is valid - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question based on the demo. It doesn't work with ```initialView: resourceTimelineMonth```

Comment: Ok. I used the code you showed...you're supposed to show us the not-working code, rather than the working code. I changed the demo to reflect what you've mentioned and yes it now reproduces (same link: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PomNNoe). This looks like it's probably a bug in fullCalendar, there's no way to affect that behaviour through config. Therefore you need to raise it with fullCalendar, there is nothing we can really do for you on Stackoverflow. See https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs for instructions.